# Game in JAR works only inside Eclipse

Tags: java, opengl, jar, jogl

I have my game in a state where it works in eclipse. My project directory looks like the image on the left.

[image]

Exporting seems to go just fine, I have some unused variables that aren't yet functional but the code works without errors. But when I double click (yes jar files are associated with the jre to run by double clicking) nothing happens. So I try it from the command line and get the error shown on the right.

Can anyone please help me, I have no idea what's going on.

note: When I exported, I exported to a runnable jar and chose the extract libraries into jar option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like eclipse only extracted the pure java libraries. Try copying all those jar libraries to your desktop or some other directory in the classpath.

Comment: inside idk.jar, i can see the dll files and the classes were intergrated in their correct package folders. Okay, i tried just having the 4 other jar files in the same directory as the idk.jar file. after doing that i can only run it in the command line. I created a batch file to launch it and later i may make a basic C++ program to launch it. although there's one more question on my mind, will this setup, if transfered to another computer with an intel processor, still work?

Comment: @Marcus13345 amd64 is supported by intel 64 bit processors so it should work.

Comment: okay so i got it working on my computer but not everybody has the "java" command, is there some way to launch it without using the java command?

Comment: Hmm... I think you can package it as an exe which loads the JVM from jvm.dll . I haven't actually tried this but IIRC this is what eclipse does. You could also distribute your app as a .jar and have the user double-click it or run "explorer app.jar" from a terminal which has the same effect as double-clicking it.

Comment: okay that will work for me, the only problem im facing now is that the amd64 natives do not work on an intel machine. when loading up the app, it stops and says it can't find the i586 natives. am i going to have to make different version of the app for different processors